# Reusing same instance of a class from multiple python modules

Tags: python, class, singleton

```
# dummy.py
class Dummy(object):
     events = []

     @classmethod
     def create(cls):
         cls.events.append(1)

     @classmethod
     def display(cls):
         print(cls.events)

# test1.py
from dummy import Dummy

Dummy.create()
Dummy.display()

# test2.py
from dummy import Dummy

Dummy.create()
Dummy.display()
```

Running 
python test1.py outputs
[1]
python test2.py outputs
[1]

Expected
I am expecting that the events list gets updated value
so when I run test2.py I get output [1, 1]
how do i achieve it?

Comment: You mean `python test1.py` & `python test2.py`? And you want `python test2.py` display 2 events?

Comment: yes python test2.py when done after python test1.py should display both events @Sraw